# Give acces to multiple users to limunati proxy zone

Tags: node.js, authentication, proxy, chromium

I'm a noobie to luminati and I'm trying to create an app where i launch chromium windows with luminati proxy, my problem is the zone management in luminati, i was wondering if luminati provide multiple email/password autentification to a zone  if not how should I manage the auth from luminati prospect or should just do it my self

Answer (score 0):

1. Luminati already has an app that launches chromium configured with it's proxy automatically, it's call the Luminati Proxy Manager.

When you install it you can open multiple ports each with it's own parameters. Each port will allow you to launch chromium with those configurations.

2. Luminati zones don't require traditional authentication. If you go to settings for your particular zone you'll see that each zone has it's own password.

Go to your Luminati control panel and click the API & Integrations tab. Choose your integration method (API, browser or code), you'll be provided with multiple authentication methods for the zone you choose.